# Reading JSON file with Python 3

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm using Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10 x64. The `JSON` file I'm reading is [this](http://pastebin.com/Yjs6FAfm) which is a `JSON` array containing 2 more arrays.

I'm trying to parse this `JSON` file using the `json` module. As described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) the `JSON` file must be compliant to `RFC 7159`. I checked my file [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and it tells me it's perfectly fine with the `RFC 7159` format, but when trying to read it using this simple python code:

```
with open(absolute_json_file_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
    text = json_file.read()
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print(json_data)
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2217, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "C:/Users/Andres Torti/Git-Repos/MCF/Sur3D.App/shapes-json-checker.py", line 14, in <module>
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Users\Andres Torti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Andres Torti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Andres Torti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Andres Torti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I can read this exact file perfectly fine on Javascript but I can't get Python to parse it. Is there anything wrong with my file or is any problem with the Python parser?

Comment: Something is wrong with the encoding of the file. For what it's worth, `requests.get("http://pastebin.com/raw/Yjs6FAfm").json()` works :)

Comment: @cricket_007 it's possible as I had to use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to avoid weird characters at the start of the file because the file is `UTF-8-BOM` not `UTF-8`

Comment: Right, the problem is at the start of the file as evident by `line 1 column 1`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, the answer from @Will Molter works, reading the text content instead of the file, maybe `json#load` is ignoring the file encoding?

Comment: Don't know about that, I thought it just did `.read()` on the file anyway.

Comment: @cricket_007 just saved the file as `UTF-8` but the problem persists. I guess I will just read it as text before parsing it, really weird

Comment: Try copy pasting the contents of the pastebin to a new file. Or try another editor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on reading over the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) again, it appears you need to either change the third line to

```
json_data = json.loads(text)
```

or remove the line

```
text = json_file.read()
```

since `read()` causes the file's index to reach the end of the file. (I suppose, alternatively, you can reset the index of the file).

Comment: This works, but why can't I open the file directly? According to this https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load I should be able to.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out; if you call `read()` first, then the the file object has its index at the end of the file and there is no longer anything left to make a json out of.

Answer (score 66):

Try this

```
import json

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    array = json.load(f)

print (array)
```

Comment: I still get the same exception, 'r' is the default opening mode

Comment: @Andres i guess the problem is with your local file. Check again.

Comment: What encoding did you use when saving the file, probably it is

Comment: @Andres I saved it as UTF-8

Comment: hey @Andres, sorry for digging on an old thread but how do you save the `.json` file in `utf-8` on a windows machine? I don't see an option in [Json Dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function. 

There is a token.json I've created on the windows machine. and it gives an encoding error to utf8 for the start byte when it's deployed to GCP which of course uses ubuntu machines on the cloud.

any suggestion is appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

For python3, only the below worked for me - none of the above.

```py
import json

with open('/emp.json', 'r') as f:

     data=f.read()

print(data)
```