# api call in python not able to return json properly

Tags: python, json, api, format

Trying to hit one api and write the output to json file, but i am getting some error related to json decode, but when i manully login into that portal, i am able to login and see values

What i tried:

```
import json
import requests
ip = sys.argv[1]
log_info = []
headers = {
    'X-Requested-By': 'cli',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('query', ip),
    ('range', '300'),
    ('limit', '100'),
    ('sort', 'timestamp:desc'),
    ('pretty', 'true'),
)
response = requests.get('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/search/universal/relative', headers=headers, params=params,
                        auth=('xxxx', 'xxxxxxxx'))
text = response.text
pretty_json = json.loads(text)
if pretty_json.get('messages'):  
 
    status = "Yes"    
else:
    status = "No"
log_info.append({"Host": ip,"Status": status})

with open(r"c:\csv\logsatest.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(log_info, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Error i am getting:

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 2)
```

any suggestion please...

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the JSON response back? Can you print your `response.text` and see what it really is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON file with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644480/reading-json-file-with-python-3)

Comment: actually i am getting  <Response [404]> but when i manually login into that portal, i am seeing values..so did my code issues ?

Comment: actually bit confused where exactly its saying error, after hitting api request or when it loads it.. or when I write actuall the output to json file.. trying to figure out when this particular type of error happens

Comment: A 404 means you hit a url which doesn't exist, are you sure the url is right?

Comment: Yeah i manually login into portal, i can do the same operation which i perform through this code ..so may be dumb question, how can i verify what is right url to hit , is there a way to get it when i manually log in (as i am able to to manual hit and get the result on portal)

Comment: @asp Maybe the Web server is configured in a way to respond with 404 if credentials are wrong... Are you 100% sure that your auth credentials are correct and that your "authenticated" request has all headers and everything else needed for successful login?

Comment: Yeah I can  log in with sane credentials manually ...